# How to convert string to normal text in JS (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

I was calling in data from an api and data has special characters. For eg in object returned :

```
{
  question : "In which year did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?"
}
```

If I store this value in a variable it saves as a string and when I call this variable using JSX, itthinks its a string and doesn't recognize special characters.

How can I solve this?

```
export default function Quiz(props){
const element = "In which year did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?"
        
    return (
         <main>
             {element}
          </main>
            )
  }
```

I want to render this on the screen

> In which year did the British television series "The Bill" end?

Comment: Can you please post your code as text, not as an image? People can't copy-paste it into their answer when it's an image.

Comment: use InnerHTML!!

Comment: This is React @AbhishekPandey. There is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but that's probably to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) to convert your HTML entities into characters by grabbing the `innerText` of the parsed body element. As we're only dealing with and rendering text content, and not HTML content, we don't need to worry about dangerously setting our HTML (with something like [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)) that could potentially lead to attacks such as XSS:

```js
const {useMemo} = React;

const App = () => {
  const element = useMemo(() => {
    const str = "In which year did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?";
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.innerText;
  }, []);
  return <p>{element}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript string method `replaceAll()`.

You can use it as `string.replaceAll`("&quot;","`\"`")

```js
string = "In which year did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?";
console.log(string.replaceAll("&quot;","\""));
```

Run the snippet and you will get the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create and call a small "sanitise" function that takes a dictionary of key/value pairs, and runs [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) on each to swap out the HTML entities.

```js
const data ={
  question: 'In which &lt;year&gt; did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?'
}

const dict = {
  '&quot;': '"',
  '&gt;': '>',
  '&lt;': '<'
};

function sanitise(str) {
  for (const key in dict) {
    str = str.replaceAll(key, dict[key]);
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(sanitise(data.question));
```

Comment: I am calling data from some quiz api that has random question and those question contains all sorts of special characters, greek letters, currency symbols. I just want to be able to show them. there must be some other way too right

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple and easy to use solution without any headache

simply install a react package called [react-render-markup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-markup)  and then import in your component where you want to convert this string to plan text it's actually a HTML markup  like that:

```
import { Markup } from 'react-render-markup';

export default function Quiz(props){ 

const element = "In which year did the British television series &quot;The Bill&quot; end?"   

return (
     <main>
         <Markup markup={element} />
     </main>
  )
}
```

And see the magic